# joomla setRedirect

Tags: joomla

How to prevent executing code after setRedirect?

I've place setRedirect in controller, it does redirect to different controller but still executing rest of the code in first controller.

Answer (score 2):

> **Usually "redirect" will return "exit()", but "setRedirect" return "void()".**

```
$application = JFactory::getApplication();
$application->enqueueMessage(JText::_('MSG'), 'Warning');
$application->redirect('index.php?option=com_rooms&task=schedule&view=schedule');
```

Answer (score 1):

like @biswarupadhikari's example, but more J! like with close() method:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->redirect('index.php?option=com_component');
$app->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php die() function after setRedirect, it's equivalent to exit()

Answer (score 0):

Use like this way

```
$mainframe=JFactory::getApplication();
$mainframe->redirect("index.php?option=com_test&task=othertask","Redirected to other task");
exit(0);
```